# Mod Rewrite and Facebook $_GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

While writing my login system, I came across a little issue when authorizing an user with Facebook...

After someone clicks the 'Login with Facebook' button and signs in/authorizes my app, Facebook redirects back to my site, with a series of `$_GET` variables, as normal. The only issue is I'd like to check if one of those variables are set in order to check the status of the Facebook login.

When I try pulling the `$_GET` var, it 'says' it doesn't exist. The issue is with my using mod_rewrite to clean up the apparence of my url:

```
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ?a=b&content=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ?a=b&content=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

This turns:
`www.mysite.com?content=login&page=2` into
`www.mysite.com/login/2`

So my url of `www.mysite.com/content?state=[...]&code=[...]&...etc` must be confusing the variables Facebook assigns, with the to be rewritten `$_GET` vars.

Same thing happens with a url with both the content and page set. eg:
`www.mysite.com/content/page?state=......`

What would be the best way of solving this? I know I could find another way to show a confirmed Facebook login, but this will continue to be an issue for other situations in the future, I'm sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[L,QSA]` instead of just `[L]`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought my situation might be unique due to me already having some rewrite code, but I should have assumed there'd already be some built in functionality. Thanks again.