# Allow php $_GET option with clean urls with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I need php to get a variable from a url even if the mod_rewrite is set.

Mod rewrite as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /*********/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1

</IfModule>
```

Example url: www.example.com/something/somthing/?search=something

On my site it does not read the $_GET varible search at all

Comment: Commonly the `[QSA]` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[QSA]` to the end of the `RewriteRule` line. Standing for **Q**uery **S**tring **A**ppend, it does exactly what it says and appends any previous query string to the rewritten address.

Comment: I've downvoted this, because it's a shallow answer and thus looks like repwhoring. In particular in light of enough duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763112/mod-rewrite-and-facebook-get-variables/14763142#14763142

Comment: Mario, that link there wouldn't of helped me due to the fact that he was having a different issue

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1&%{QUERY_STRING}` would work too.